# Python installation on Windows failing

Tags: python

I've been trying to install python on windows 7 , but I am getting this error near the end of the install and the entire thing rolls back. [image: Python install error]

I have tried both 2.7.2 and 3.2.2 32 and 64bit versions, does anyone know how I may fix this ?

Comment: Do you have pending updates?  I've had assemblies fail to install until I restart the computer due to [unseen] pending updates.

Comment: Actually I do, Will restart and report back.

Comment: MackieChan if you want to add that as an answer I will accept it, restarting to apply the updates worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting.  Occasionally windows will just silently fail when installing assemblies because it has pending updates.